# How to sort multiple range of value based on the increasing value of multiple different column?

Tags: linux, shell, perl, awk

I have a problem in sorting some value from input.txt file, and I still didn't have any idea how to solve it.

Input File (input.txt):

```
1 5 1 2183 2006 6001 6132
1 6 1 2183 2006 6001 6133
1 7 1 2183 2006 6001 6134
...
1 65 1 2183 2006 6001 6227
1 66 1 2183 2006 6001 6234
1 67 1 2183 2006 6001 6235
1 68 1 2183 2006 6004 6156
1 69 1 2183 2006 6004 6157
1 70 1 2183 2006 6004 6158
...
1 115 1 2183 2006 6004 6227
1 116 1 2183 2006 6004 6234
1 117 1 2183 2006 6004 6235
1 118 1 2183 2006 6007 6120
1 119 1 2183 2006 6007 6146
1 120 1 2183 2006 6007 6147
...
1 182 1 2183 2006 6007 6237
1 183 1 2183 2006 6007 6238
1 184 1 2183 2006 6007 6239
```

Desired Output File (output.txt):

```
1 2183 2006 5-67 6001 6132 6235
1 2183 2006 68-117 6004 6156 6235
1 2183 2006 118-184 6007 6120 6239
```

There are 7 columns/fields in input file. Column 1,3,4,5 should be constant value. While column 2 and column 6 changes are depending on column 7. Column 6 has increment value of 3, and column 7 changes are vary and only change on the last 3 digits; example 6**132**, 6**133**, 6**134**.

The trick is on output column 4, how do I sort and unseq it based on changes of input column 6 and 7?

> Let assume if:
>
> input column 6 (6001) and input column 7 (6132) reached the last
>   value before the next input column 6 (6004) and input column 7 (6235)
>
> then, the final output column 4 should have value 5-67, output column
>   5 should have the same value 6001, output column 6 should have the
>   first input column 7 and the output column 7 (6132) should have the
>   last input column 7 (6235).

```
Example 1st batch:

Input:
1 5 1 2183 2006 6001 6132
1 6 1 2183 2006 6001 6133
1 7 1 2183 2006 6001 6134
...
1 65 1 2183 2006 6001 6227
1 66 1 2183 2006 6001 6234
1 67 1 2183 2006 6001 6235

Desired Output:
1 2183 2006 5-67 6001 6132 6235


Example 2nd batch:
Input:
1 68 1 2183 2006 6004 6156
1 69 1 2183 2006 6004 6157
1 70 1 2183 2006 6004 6158
...
1 115 1 2183 2006 6004 6227
1 116 1 2183 2006 6004 6234
1 117 1 2183 2006 6004 6235

Desired Output:
1 2183 2006 68-117 6004 6156 6235


Example 3rd batch:

Input:
1 118 1 2183 2006 6007 6120
1 119 1 2183 2006 6007 6146
1 120 1 2183 2006 6007 6147
...
1 181 1 2183 2006 6007 6236
1 182 1 2183 2006 6007 6237
1 183 1 2183 2006 6007 6238
1 184 1 2183 2006 6007 6239

Desired Output:
1 2183 2006 118-184 6007 6120 6239
```

When the desired output compiled, it should become like the following:

```
1 2183 2006 5-67 6001 6132 6235
1 2183 2006 68-117 6004 6156 6235
1 2183 2006 118-184 6007 6120 6239
```

Could you please advise on this?

Comment: This is not at all clear, please keep your question simple with small and simple input and expected output and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$6 != col6 {
    printf fmt, min2, max2, min7, max7
    fmt = $1 " " $4 " " $5 " %d-%d " $6 " %d %d\n"

    min2 = max2 = $2
    min7 = max7 = $7

    col6 = $6
}
{
    if ($2 < min2)
        min2 = $2
    else if ($2 > max2)
        max2 = $2

    if ($7 < min7)
        min7 = $7
    else if ($7 > max7)
        max7 = $7
}
END {
    printf fmt, min2, max2, min7, max7
}
```

Comment: Hi oguzismall, this works perfectly like I want. Thanks a lot pal, couldn't done without you.

Answer (score 3):

Rows of columnar data you want to group by and find things like the min and max of columns screams database. So... scripting sqlite3:

```
#!/bin/sh
sqlite3 -batch -noheader -list -separator ' ' <<EOF
CREATE TABLE data(c1 INTEGER, c2 INTEGER, c3 INTEGER, c4 INTEGER
                , c5 INTEGER, c6 INTEGER, c7 INTEGER);
.import "$1" data
SELECT c1, c4, c5, min(c2) || '-' || max(c2), c6, min(c7), max(c7)
FROM data GROUP BY c6 ORDER BY c6;
EOF
```

With your sample input:

```
$ ./doit.sh input.txt
1 2183 2006 5-67 6001 6132 6235
1 2183 2006 68-117 6004 6156 6235
1 2183 2006 118-184 6007 6120 6239
```

Comment: This works very well too, it is simple and easy to understand, unfortunately I didn't use sqlite in my project. Thanks Shawn :)

Comment: @oguzismail Lately I've really been getting into using sqlite in shell scripts for working with data that's easily loaded into a table. A surprising number of things that get complex or ugly in other languages or tools can be trivial to do in SQL. It's like `join(1)` on steroids.